# How to share resources from xcode project into other xcode project within a workspace with out using static library?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am currently working with workspace,i have multiple projects within a workspace and firstly, i want to add a file/any resources/framework which is present in one xcode project to other projects within the workspace. Is there any other way to share resources to other project with out using static library?

and secondly, i want to know how to run multiple schemes within a target in workspace?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To share a file or a resource between two different workspace, you can add it to your project and uncheck the option "Copy resource to project". In these way the file'll not be moved from the original position in the filesystem, and it can be added to 2 different project.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! Works beautifully!
I think this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try working with "source trees": In Xcode go to menu Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations > Source Trees! see [Source Trees Preferences Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_trees_preferences/About.html).

Running multiple schemes is also easy!
Duplicate and rename a existing one and re-configure it as you need!
Then in your targets build settings you can specify different settings for different schemes where appropriate!